# adding date from calendar to sql server 2008

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, sql-insert

I am working on a project in asp.net c# which I am getting date from two calendars and storing them in database fields specified as datetime in SprintsN table, sql server 2008 database. But I am getting an exception

**Exception:**

> insert into SprintsN (S_Duration, S_Staus, P_ID StartDate,EstEndDate)
>   values('1week', 'incomplete','5','2015-05-01 12:00:00','2015-05-07
>   12:00:00');System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect
>   syntax near 'StartDate'. at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
>   Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at

**code:**

Calendars events:

```
 protected void Calendar2_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     EstDate = Calendar2.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
     EstDateBox.Text = EstDate;
     Calendar2.Visible = false;
  }

  protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {  
      startdate = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
      SDate.Text = startdate;
      Calendar1.Visible = false;
  }
```

Sql Database storage handler:

```
String query="";
try { 
    query = "insert into SprintsN (S_Duration, S_Staus, P_ID StartDate,EstEndDate) values('" + SprintDurBox.Text + "', 'incomplete','" + p_ID + "','"+startdate+"','"+EstDate+"');";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(str);
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
    con.Open();

    if (com.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
    {
        SprintStatus.Text = "Sprint Successfully Saved";
    }
    else
    {
        SprintStatus.Text = "Sprint  not Saved";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Response.Write(query);
    Response.Write(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: have you used the debugger to step through the code..? also can you tell us the actual value when you step over this variable for example `startdate` most important I would convert your Insert command to utilize Parameterized query

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first part of your query, looks like you're missing a comma.

`insert into SprintsN (S_Duration, S_Staus, P_ID StartDate,EstEndDate)`

should be:

`insert into SprintsN (S_Duration, S_Staus, P_ID, StartDate,EstEndDate)`

Comment: Thanks Sir the exception is handled.